# Changing Spree Default Image Size, 3.6 with ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, rails-activestorage

I'm using Spree 3.6 with Rails 5.2. Spree provides the documentation for older systems with PaperClip, but there is no decimation for the newer systems with Active Storage.
Anyone has experience with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To change the default image dimensions or add new ones you need to create a decorator file `app/models/spree/image_decorator.rb`:

```
module YourApplication
  module Spree
    module ImageDecorator
      module ClassMethods
        def styles
          {
            mini:    '48x48>',
            small:   '100x100>',
            product: '240x240>',
            large:   '600x600>',
          }
        end
      end

      def self.prepended(base)
        base.singleton_class.prepend ClassMethods
      end
    end
  end
end

Spree::Image.prepend ::YourApplication::Spree::ImageDecorator
```

https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/images.html